# How could I implement a bleach bypass shader effect for WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, hlsl, pixel-shader

How could I implement a [bleach bypass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleach_bypass) shader effect for WPF?
I'm also interested in the possibility of implementing the first two [Tehnicolor Film Processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technicolor#Process_1), or any variety that would result in an old film look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/shaderlibrary/packages/post_bleach_bypass.fx.zip

The important part is:

```
float4 bypassPS(QuadVertexOutput IN, uniform sampler2D SceneSampler) : COLOR
{
    float4 base = tex2D(SceneSampler, IN.UV);
    float3 lumCoeff = float3(0.25,0.65,0.1);
    float lum = dot(lumCoeff,base.rgb);
    float3 blend = lum.rrr;
    float L = min(1,max(0,10*(lum- 0.45)));
    float3 result1 = 2.0f * base.rgb * blend;
    float3 result2 = 1.0f - 2.0f*(1.0f-blend)*(1.0f-base.rgb);
    float3 newColor = lerp(result1,result2,L);
    float A2 = Opacity * base.a;
    float3 mixRGB = A2 * newColor.rgb;
    mixRGB += ((1.0f-A2) * base.rgb);
    return float4(mixRGB,base.a);
}
```